# Is there a better way to access Angular's components private properties?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If you pass a component reference into a function you can access Component's properties through a private property called ɵcmp, for example:

```
myFunction(TestComponent);

export function myFunction (component) {
  console.log('this is the component selector', component.ɵcmp.selectors[0]);
  console.log('these are component inputs', component.ɵcmp.inputs)
}
```

Is there any better way to access those properties without accessing this "magic" private property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v12 and below you could inject and then use `ComponentFactoryResolver` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver)) to get the components `ComponentFactory` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory)) which gives public access to those properties:

```
const factory: ComponentFactory = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TestComponent);
console.log(factory.selector);
console.log(factory.inputs);
console.log(factory.outputs);
```

Although this method is now marked as deprecated in v13.